# Xcode key binding ^⌘↑ / ^⌘↓ / ^⌘→ / ^⌘← not working

Tags: xcode

I have reset my key binding setting, but it still invalid.

[image]

but if I changed the key, it will working.

what's wrong?

Comment: There's a chance that you have a conflict for those key bindings. Do they show up in relevant "conflicts" section?

Comment: I checked up, but there are no conflict for those.

Comment: Don't you have bound the key to another function in Shortcuts in System Preferences's Keyboard section?

Comment: @Satachito Thank you for your help.. I solved this by cut down other application, and i will change the key binding for other app.